# Why do these two command variants, which are similar, give different outputs?

Tags: bash

Command 1:

```
$ rm hello.txt 2>/dev/null || { echo “Couldn’t delete hello.txt” }
"Couldn't delete hello.txt"
```

Command 2

```
$ rm hello.txt 2>/dev/null || { echo 'Couldn’t delete hello.txt' }
Couldn't delete hello.txt
```

---

**Note:** `hello.txt` doesn't exist in the current directory.

Comment: I assume for bash `“` and `”` are not quotes.

Comment: the `rm` part is completely irrelevant here. It's all about the `echo` part

Comment: Neither command would do as you say. Any command in `{ ...; }` must always end in semi-colon or a newline character.

Answer (score 16):

The first command

```
rm hello.txt 2>/dev/null || { echo “Couldn’t delete hello.txt” }
```

contains the characters `<U+201C>`(LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK), `<U+2019>` (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) and `<U+201D>` (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) which are in no way special to the shell and are output as such.

The second command

```
rm hello.txt 2>/dev/null || { echo 'Couldn’t delete hello.txt' }
```

contains a string enclosed in single quotes; the character between `n` and `t` is again `<U+2019>`, which is not special to the shell.

Answer (score 1):

The pair `“”` is called [smart quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark). Similarly, your `’` in `Couldn’t` is also a smart quote.

Those are unlike normal quotes in the sense that they're *curly* to differentiate the begin and end of the quoting part. ***They have no meaning in most (if not all) programming/scripting languages*** I know and are just the same as other Unicode characters.

So your first `echo` doesn't actually have any quote and the command will receive those words **as separate arguments**. You can check that easily

```bash
$ for s in “Couldn’t delete hello.txt”; do echo $s; done
“Couldn’t
delete
hello.txt”

$ for s in 'Couldn’t delete hello.txt'; do echo $s; done
Couldn’t delete hello.txt
```

In fact **your output is wrong** (did you really copy paste it?) because there's no way smart quotes become normal quotes after `echo`. The output should still be smart quote as in my example above

As you can see, the second case is a *single* string containing a Unicode character outside the ASCII range, so the quotes will be stripped by the shell

See [What are curly quotes and can I use them in my code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/704762/44425)