# Bash: psql command not found when called inside a function

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, postgresql

I have a bash script, where the psql connect string is stored in a variable.

After this I have defined three functions.
—————————

```
export PC="usr/bin/psql --host=abx --port=1234 --dbname=A --username=user"

function one
{
$PC<<EOF
SEL 1;
EOF
}

function two
{
while IFS= read -r line
do
 three $line
done < file
}

function three
{
if [ $1 == Y ]
then
$PC<<EOF
Update table;
EOF
fi
}

#main function
one
two
```

————————

When I execute the script, function `one` works, retrieves data from the database, but function `three` invoked from function `two` keeps failing with the message

```
bash: psql -u …($PC expanded): command not found
```

I have checked both the `PATH` variable and `IFS`, no issues there.

Now, if I use the expanded `$PC` inside the function `three` definition, then it works.

So only when I use a variable it fails? Any ideas?

Comment: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/108618) [What are curly quotes and can I use them in my code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/704762/108618)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Would you care to explain? I am able to run the command stored in a variable from first function. Only when I call it from a function within a function it fails. How is quotes/braces significant here?

Comment: @roaima sorry, that was a typo in question. I am using straight quotes in the actual code. Corrected it in question now.

Comment: "_I am able to run the command stored in a variable from first function_" - it's an unreliable way of running a command. Use functions for commands and variables for data

Comment: @roaima I Agree, but unfortunately I cannot change the method. This variable in question is set in a master script that’s read only and we just source them in other scripts. Even if I were to use a function here in my script, I will have to use this variable, and that again yields the same result.

Comment: Then you need to tell the author of the master script that they are using functions and variables incorrectly. This is a common cause of unexpected errors

Comment: @roaima Alright. But could you please help me understand why this particular function alone fails to recognize a properly expanded variable as a command, while the initial function can? 
And thanks for the responses.. I appreciate it..

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but what if you tweaked your code to be something like this?

```
pc()
{
  /usr/bin/psql --host=abx --port=1234 --dbname=A --username=user
}

one()
{
  pc << EOF
SEL 1;
EOF
}

two()
{
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
    three "$line"
  done
}

three()
{
  if [ "$1" = Y ]
  then
    pc << EOF
Update table;
EOF
  fi
}

# main function

one
two < file
```

Comment: Hi Jim, Thanks for the reply. 
Yes, this works. So does using the expanded value directly in function defintion. 
Any idea why the variable method would work in a function, but not from within a second function, even when its getting expanded correctly?

Comment: Thanks, @roaima!  Yes, my reply was rather hastily done.

Comment: @roaima Yes, I typically do.  Again, too much cut-and-paste.

Comment: @Bash3d it seems that  `while IFS= ` is overwriting the `IFS` variable (this is set to `''` empty string) and is passed to function three. I was unable to reproduce your behavior,  all works well in my machine (I'm using Linux and bash version is 5.2.15).

Comment: @Bash3d A possible solution in your case is in `function three` add this line at the beginning: `IFS=' '` (set IFS to a space char) and instead of using curly braces for your function, you can use parenthesis. It'd be: `three() ( your code )`. Or instead of parenthesis in your function three you can call this one by using: `(three "$line")` in your `function two`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I too suspected that IFS is messing up the command. So tried setting the IFS back to default inside function three before the command, but to no avail. It really irks me that I can’t find an explanation for this weird behaviour.
I will try using parenthesis in function definition as you suggested, but doubt a sub shell is going to help. Will test and update here in some time. 
Thanks!